# Find an algorithm for put all the Uppercases behind the Lowercases that relative order is not changed

Tags: string, algorithm

Now I have a string just including uppercases and lowercases. I want to change the string to the form that all the uppercases are behind the lowercases, and, the relative order of all the uppercases or the lowercases is not changed.

For example, a string "aAbBcCDd" changes to "abcdABCD". A string "aaAAAbb" changes to "aabbAAA".

if I define length of string an "N", now I have an algorithm that is O(NlogN). But I want to know if there is an algorithm that costs smaller time. Of course , memory is limited too. The memory don't depend on the Length is most fantastic.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: you could do something like a bucket sort where you defined two buckets (lowercase and uppercase)

Comment: Does it have to be completely in-place?  There is a completely trivial O(n) algorithm if you make a new string.

Comment: one more solution: you implement any generic sorting algorithm with one addition: compare function should take to account that 'a' < 'z';  'A' < 'Z' but 'z' < 'A'. The last relation reflects the specific rule of your assignment, not the natural relation of ASCII characters.

Comment: As @RayToal implies, it basically comes down to a question of whether you're more interested in speed or memory usage. I'm pretty sure for a comparison-based in-place version, O(n log n) is the best you can do (that's the best possible for comparison-based sorting). If you don't mind linear memory usage, O(N) is trivial.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I think you are right.The essence of this problem is sorting, and as you say, for comparison-based sorting, O(n log n) is the best. Think you very much.

Comment: @gtgaxiola, thank you for answering:) The algorithm is right but it costs too much memory.

Comment: @RayToal, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

**Input**:  Your String in mixed lower and upper case

**Output**: A String with lower case then upper case (relative order not changed)

```
Create two temporary Strings
String lower
String upper

loop over each character in your Input String

if char is upper
   append to upper
if char is lower
   append to lower

return concatenation of lower + upper
```

Comment: please defined too much memory...I guess if you don't want to create more Strings then in-place sorting will not be better than O(NlogN)

Comment: Yes. You are right. I want to find an algorithm that time is smaller than O(nlogn) and the memory don't depend on the Input. But now I know maybe that is impossible. Thank you:)